# RewriteCond if folder with parametername exists

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, folder-redirection

I want to make a subdomain-redirect if a folder with the same name as the typed subdomain exists.
e.g. I have some folder-structure like
`www.mysite.de/mainpage/hui.php`
and want to be able to access it with 
`mainpage.mysite.de/hui.php`

However, I want to let it only do that when there is acutally a folder mainpage and do that for other folders, too.
If the folder does not exists, I want to fall back to the current htacces that takes the subdomain and uses it as a parameter for the index.php. That part works well so far.

So, I have already done something like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule mainpage/([^/?]*)/?(.*)$ http://$1.mysite.de/$2 [L,R]
```

that changes the URI from `www.mysite.de/mainpage/hui.php` to `mainpage.mysite.de/hui.php`, but I also want to make the page accessable from `mainpage.mysite.de/hui.php`.

So, I thought maybe something like

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*).mysite.de$ mainpage/$1 -d
RewriteRule mainpage/([^/?]*)/?(.*)$ http://$1.mysite.de/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Of course this code doesn't work, but does someone know how this could be done?

Comment: You seem to want to redirect _both_ ways?

Comment: @w3d well, I would like let `mainpage.mysite.de/hui.php` access `www.mysite.de/mainpage/hui.php`, but also `abc.mysite.de/hui2.php` if an abc-folder exists. how can I check that?